# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ۱۵۳۶۱۹۸۶۸۴۰۰۸۵۴۲۵۴۱

Tags: android, sqlite

all.

I've found in bugsense for Android application this exeception:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ۱۵۳۶۱۹۸۶۸۴۰۰۸۵۴۲۵۴۱ (code 1): , while compiling:

```
SELECT * FROM by_istin_android_xcore_source_DataSourceRequestEntity WHERE (_id = -۱۵۳۶۱۹۸۶۸۴۰۰
```

Seems like try to select with filter by arabic number.

Someone see it before?

Comment: Can you please share the entire query?

Comment: seems like it String.format issue, I'll make changes and check. If all  will success add solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `_id` is a numeric column, you must change your code to generate numbers with ASCII digits.

If `_id` contains strings, you must change your code to 'quote' the string.